# SpringBoot - Websphere - Java Config - web.xml - resource-ref

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

I have a web application where I have 3 jndi resources defined in the web.xml
1 for the database and 2 for dyna cache

How can I convert it into Java configuration in Spring boot.

Following is the sample resource ref configuration in the application

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Resource reference for database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dbname</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref id="cache1">
    <description>cache1 description</description>
    <res-ref-name>cache/cache1</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref id="cache2">
    <description>cache2 description</description>
    <res-ref-name>cache/cache2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.ibm.websphere.cache.DistributedMap</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm a Spring user, but not Spring Boot. What kind of Spring configuration do you use? Is it XML file(s), or just annotation-based configuration?

Comment: Currently its a spring mvc app with web.xml. I want to move the application to Spring boot and convert the configuration into java based annotations.

Comment: Have you tried using `@Resource(name="jdbc/dbname")`?

Comment: You have to put those in a `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file.

Comment: Spring Boot and Embedded Servers only supporting Tomcat, Jetty and Undertow. Are you going to migrate from WebSphere to any above one of them?

Comment: @MillerCyChan, with Spring Boot, you can build a war without an embedded server and deploy to any web server, including Websphere.

Comment: I got this to work using `spring-boot-liberty` and doing it the old fashioned way with `web.xml` and `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. It should be doable in java configuration, but haven't tested it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple Databases in Spring Boot**

More on / Font: [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

Spring Boot can simplify the configuration above.

By default, **Spring Boot will instantiate its default DataSource with the configuration properties prefixed by spring.datasource.*:**

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
```

We now want to keep using the same way to configure the second DataSource, but with a different property namespace:

```
spring.second-datasource.jdbcUrl = [url]
spring.second-datasource.username = [username]
spring.second-datasource.password = [password]
```

Because we want the Spring Boot autoconfiguration to pick up those different properties (and instantiate two different DataSources), we'll define two configuration classes similar to the previous sections:

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-multiple-db-boot.properties"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
       basePackages = "com.baeldung.multipledb.dao.user",
       entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager",
       transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager")
     public class PersistenceUserAutoConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource userDataSource() {
      return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
   // userEntityManager bean 

   // userTransactionManager bean
}
```

.

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-multiple-db-boot.properties"})
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
   basePackages = "com.baeldung.multipledb.dao.product", 
   entityManagerFactoryRef = "productEntityManager", 
   transactionManagerRef = "productTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceProductAutoConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.second-datasource")
public DataSource productDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

// productEntityManager bean 

// productTransactionManager bean
}
```

Now we have defined the data source properties inside persistence-multiple-db-boot.properties according to the Boot autoconfiguration convention.

The interesting part is annotating the data source bean creation method with @ConfigurationProperties. We just need to specify the corresponding config prefix. Inside this method, we're using a DataSourceBuilder, and Spring Boot will automatically take care of the rest.

But how do the configured properties get injected into the DataSource configuration?

When calling the build() method on the DataSourceBuilder, it'll call its private bind() method:

```
public T build() {
    Class<? extends DataSource> type = getType();
    DataSource result = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(type);
    maybeGetDriverClassName();
    bind(result);
    return (T) result;
 }
```

This private method performs much of the autoconfiguration magic, binding the resolved configuration to the actual DataSource instance:

```
private void bind(DataSource result) {
    ConfigurationPropertySource source = new 
 MapConfigurationPropertySource(this.properties);
    ConfigurationPropertyNameAliases aliases = new 
ConfigurationPropertyNameAliases();
    aliases.addAliases("url", "jdbc-url");
    aliases.addAliases("username", "user");
    Binder binder = new Binder(source.withAliases(aliases));
    binder.bind(ConfigurationPropertyName.EMPTY, Bindable.ofInstance(result));
}
```

Although we don't have to touch any of this code ourselves, it's still useful to know what's happening under the hood of the Spring Boot autoconfiguration.

Besides this, the Transaction Manager and Entity Manager beans configuration is the same as the standard Spring application.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.yours.persistence.dao")
public class PersistenceJNDIConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
      throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em 
          = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());

        // rest of entity manager configuration
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("jdbc/dbname");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    // rest of persistence configuration
}
```

We’re going to use a simple model with the @Entity annotation with a generated id and a name:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    // default getters and setters
}
```

Let’s define a simple repository:

```
@Repository
public class FooDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Foo> findAll() {
        return entityManager
          .createQuery("from " + Foo.class.getName()).getResultList();
    }
}
```

And lastly, let’s create a simple service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooDao dao;

    public List<Foo> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
}
```

With this, you have everything you need in order to use your JNDI datasource in your Spring application.